# I have info on cycle counts in a warehouse that count the same locations multiple times. I want to get the latest NET_VAR for a specific location

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used `MAX(Date)` and that will get me what i need until i put the qty in the mix, since they get different results after they fix things it has multiple answers and makes me group by the qty which in the end gives me multiple results. i just want the last count numbers.

```
SELECT (CH.MOD_DATE_TIME),LH.LOCN_BRCD ,DSP_SKU, (CH.ACTL_INVN_QTY-CH.EXPTD_QTY) "NET VAR" FROM CYCLE_COUNT_HIST CH , LOCN_HDR LH, ITEM_MASTER IM WHERE CH.WHSE = 'SH1' AND CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID AND CH.SKU_ID = IM.SKU_ID AND IM.CD_MASTER_ID = '147001' and DSP_SKU LIKE 'JBLBAR31BLKAM' AND LH.LOCN_BRCD = 'HAHK42A01' AND trunc(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) > SYSDATE-120
```

It returns 3 rows of results and I want the most recent line only. I plan to modify this to (`select dsp_sku, sum(NET_VAR`) in the end to run a summary of the sku.

Comment: SELECT (CH.MOD_DATE_TIME),LH.LOCN_BRCD ,DSP_SKU, (CH.ACTL_INVN_QTY-CH.EXPTD_QTY) "NET VAR"
 FROM
  CYCLE_COUNT_HIST CH , LOCN_HDR LH, ITEM_MASTER IM
WHERE
  CH.WHSE = 'SH1'
  AND CH.LOCN_ID = LH.LOCN_ID
  AND CH.SKU_ID = IM.SKU_ID
  AND IM.CD_MASTER_ID = '147001'
              and DSP_SKU LIKE 'JBLBAR31BLKAM'
              AND LH.LOCN_BRCD = 'HAHK42A01'
AND               trunc(CH.CREATE_DATE_TIME) > SYSDATE-120

Comment: THE CODE THAT WILL RUN IS ABOVE AND WILL GIVE ME THE BELOW RESULTS

Comment: MOD_DATE_TIME         LOCN_BRCD DSP_SKU         NET VAR
1/13/2020 8:31:44 AM HAHK42A01 JBLBAR31BLKAM 0
1/13/2020 8:31:43 AM HAHK42A01 JBLBAR31BLKAM 3
1/10/2020 7:21:47 AM HAHK42A01 JBLBAR31BLKAM 3

Comment: SORRY FOR THE ALIGNMENT BUT IT HAS 3 ROWS OF RESULTS AND I WANT THE MOST RECENT LINE

Comment: Please do not put code in comments.  nobody can read this. Edit the question and put the query and sample data and results in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use subquery.

You just need to put the following condition in where clause:

```
where .....
      AND
      CH.MOD_DATE_TIME = (select MAX( MOD_DATE_TIME)
                          from cycle_count_hist)
```